# webgl2 on Android Simulator

Tags: android, webgl, unity-webgl

I try to display a web content built by Unity using webgl2 on Android Simulator based on Android 12.
It works correctly on simulator running on Linux Host but not on the same simulator running on Windows Host.

Can someone tell me why those different behaviors ?

```
val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8000")
```

On Windows 10 : "WebGL2 is not supported"
On Windows 11 : "both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed"

I use this command on host side to run the webserver: python -m http.server

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using to open it? Most likely browser engines are different. According caniuse, only [IE](https://caniuse.com/webgl2) doesn't support WebGL 2. Maybe Android simulator by Windows use IE engine to open web page

Comment: yes maybe, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using http-server of npm package and enable CORS
And also by forcing the opengles 3.0 renderer on the simulator advanced settings